# I need to buy it quickly while there are the discounts. ("the" article - ?)

Tags: definite-article

> I need to buy it quickly while there are **the** discounts in the shops.

If we speak about discounts *[in general, not only on that product]* in some non mentioned shops in our city during this week, do we need to put "the" article before "discounts"?

Comment: A period when many shops are giving discounts is called _the sales_ - an individual shop has _a sale_.

Comment: Colloquially - I need to buy it quickly while the sales are [still] on.